# Logging Who Restarted Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to log who ordered a Jenkins restart? The log right now just denotes that a restart happened. I would like something like

```
Mar 30, 2015 9:57:01 PM INFO: Safe-restart started by GregWringle.
```

Is there anyway I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins does this various restarts, but for restart after installing a plugin it puts the user as anonymous. There's an [audit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin) that records the user name.